# Wordpress WooCommerce: "Place Order" does not work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using 1.6.6 version of WooCommerce and I have a problem:

When Payment Gateways -> PayPal -> " Use form submission method. " is checked - and I'm trying to checkout - the "place order" button gives me the "loading" fade animation and then redirects me back to the checkout page (like just refreshes).

When it's not checked, the "place order" button works and I can checkout but i don't get the order details from PayPal.

I'm using BlueHost.

Thanks in advance,

Avni.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

"404 Redirected" plugin just caught all the calls with ?querystring and never gave a reply.

damn.